# Литература по эффективному программированию процессоров (DMA, прерывания)

Tags: микроконтроллеры, процессор

Всем привет!

Я хотел бы найти хорошую литературу по программированию микропроцессоров/микроконтроллеров (например с ядром Cortex-M0, Cortex-M3), где качественно описывается использование прерываний и контроллера ПДП. Не так как в даташите, сухой пример использования конкретной периферии независимо от всего остального, а хорошее пособие по написанию программ.

Интересует прежде всего печатный вариант (книги, учебники) а не отдельные статьи, но их тоже почитаю. Заранее прошу не предлагать статьи из первой страницы поиска в гугле "использование DMA" и т.д., так я и сам умею.

Имеется опыт программирования контроллеров AVR, знания C/C++, ассемблера.

Answer (score 2):

Подробные статьи по применению стоит посмотреть в ежеквартальнике Бюллютень TI, скачать можно на сайте scanti.ru. К сожалению подобные труды, которые вас интересуют, в природе маловероятны. Сам модуль DMA и его связи с периферией настолько узкоспециализированные и индивидуальные для каждого конкретного процессора, что паттернов его использования более глобальных чем "разгон" конкретного интерфейса и высвобождение процессорных ресурсов для задач не связанных с пересылкой данных в общем случае описать невозможно. Однако, если у вас есть конкретные вопросы по возможностям применерия, могу на них ответить.

Comment: Спасибо, гляну на сайте. Вы работаете с железом? Тогда я задам еще один вопрос. 
Посоветуйте книги по написанию правильных программ для процессоров/микроконтроллеров (в плане подводных камней, грамотного использования таймеров для разных задач, правильного планирования и обработки прерываний, как не нужно писать программы и т.д.)

Comment: Да, я занимаюсь железом на продукции TI но, кроме их журнала, даташитов и юзергайдов никакой литературы не видел. В случае техас инструментс, спасает их среда разработки, которая имеет встроенный анализатор оптимальности кода и дает подсказки по правильному стилю программирования под конкретный кристалл в зависимости от его аппаратной структуры. Также можно найти литературу, скорее статьи, чем книги, по тонкостям программирования под конкретный процессор, но так чтобы общие правила для всех - нигде не видел.

Comment: Пиар-компания TI значит.

Comment: Хотелось бы, но нет. Исторически сложилось. Факультативно писал под пики, по работе иногда тоже. Но CCS как среда разработки мне ближе и удобнее. Плюс теже arm ядра для авионики выпускает из доступных только ТИ, аналогично с fram микроконтроллерами. Добавьте к этому доступность отладочных комплектов от 5 до 50$ для макетирования изделий на соплях и проводочках и обилие референс дизайнов по применению решений. Как инженер я выбираю то на чем быстро могу произвести макетирование, разработку и отдать в производство. Наличие hal, csl и ртос под большинство кристаллов ТИ этому очень способствуют. Н